# Can you give custom attribute to select options in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, onchange

Can you give custom attribute to select options in LWC?
I'm trying to give the last option a onchange attribute.

.html

```html
<template>
   <lightning-checkbox-group name="CheckboxGroup"
       label="Choose one"
       data-id="checkbox"
       options={options}
       value={value}
       onchange={handleInputVal} 
       required
   >
   </lightning-checkbox-group>
</template>
```

.js

```js
get options() {
    return [
        { label: "1", value: "l1" },
        { label: "2", value: "2" },
        { label: "3", value: "3", onchange: "{handleUncheck}" }, // this here
    ];
}

handleUncheck(e) {

}
```

Seems like I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `onchange` should only reside on the lightning-`lightning-checkbox-group` component, if you add it to your options, they wont individually trigger when the value changes.

you want to handle everything  `handleInputVal` function, and then from there delegate to another function if necessary based on the selected value.

Comment: That made sense. Thanks!